# Kafka for intra-day visualization, monitoring and command processing

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

I have 20 or so processes that generate logs (~500MB each) on their respective servers and so far I've been replicating these logs to a central server and writing GUIs and monitoring that tail these replicated log files directly.

I setup Kafka and used fluent-bit to successfully replicate the logs to a partition per each of my servers and this seems to work very well.

I'm a bit confused on the client side since I only care about data on a per-day basis (each of my source log files have a date in the filename).

Is it generally good practice to delete all of my kafka topics at the end of the day?  I understand that there is per-client offset tracking built in to kafka but I don't want to take any risks and further, I don't see much of a point to bootstrap from the beginning of time either.

Another approach might be to add the date to the topic name?  So I would essentially be creating 20 new topics per day.  I think the upside of this would be that it will pretty much guarantee my data is only for that day.  Also previous days' data would also be available and I could just delete these topics after a week or month or so.

My client processes include:

1. Graphing data from the logs on a per-day basis; 1 graph per server process (20 total)
2. Insert certain data pulled from the logs into a database
3. Monitor log files for issues (grepping on strings, etc..) and alert users through a custom GUI
4. Run some stats/analytics on the data and produce end of day reports
5. Config GUI that will send config changes over kafka to server processes.  Server processes echo the changes back so user gets confirmation.  This would operate on a separate topic to the logs.  The topic can be shared among server processes as the process name is added to the json message (so consumers know if it's for them or not).

Or perhaps Kafka might not be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Elasticsearch and Kibana? (Optionally Filebeat instead of Fluentd)

Kafka Connect dumps data in realtime, you slice the data from Kibana to do searches by day, or whatever. Create Kibana dashboards that can update in realtime or few times per day

Don't delete Kafka topics unless you are setting up some dynamic time-based routing within fluent-bit. Kafka has a week of retained data by default, but you can set your topics to retain 24hours worth of data

However, Kafka isn't really even required here. Lookup the "EFK stack", Elastic, Fluentd, Kibana, or if using Beats you can remove the need for Fluentd

Plus, with the recent open release of Elastic XPack, you can set alerts for searches and do anomaly detection in your data

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm actually most interested in the messaging component of getting data between hosts and applications and thought Kafka would do well instead of redis or zeromq for instance.  I use elasticsearch and kibana for other uses but for my particular use I really need a message broker.  My question is more to know if Kafka itself would be a good fit for my needs.

Comment: Kafka does more than just messaging and queueing. If you don't care about storing the data and can immediately send it elsewhere, go ahead and use any other message broker technology that's existed over the last few decades. If all you have is log files, then you can configure fluentbit or Filebeat with different output destinations... Hadoop is typically used for storing and processing that amount of data you have.

Comment: Thanks again!  I think for me the differentiator between Kafka and other message brokers is that Kafka can retain this data directly.  This particularly helps if I need to restart an application during the day for instance.  I understand for longer term storage, one would use elasticsearch, influxdb, etc.. but as I mentioned my use-case is really just the message queuing (with intraday retention).  I take it Kafka should do a good job with this?

Comment: It'll work fine, but as mentioned, other options will also work. I'm not going to force you to use Kafka over anything else